# PrimeFaces ImageSwitch component stop on last image

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this code on my view:

```
<p:imageSwitch effect="none" slideshowAuto="false" widgetVar="images">
    <ui:repeat var="image" value="#{indexController.cd.imagesView}">
        <o:graphicImage value="#{imagesController.get(indexController.name, image)}" />
    </ui:repeat>
</p:imageSwitch>
```

and this bean to load the images

```
@GraphicImageBean
public class ImagesController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6497820188225935778L;

    private static final String APP_PATH = System.getProperty("application.path");

    public byte[] get(String name, String file) {           
        String path = APP_PATH.concat(name).concat(File.separator).concat(file);

        try {
            return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I need that when it is in the last image the component stops and don't go to the first image again.

There's a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Answered below and tested it myself on the PrimeFaces showcase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  So first let's show you how to Stop the slideShow.  Go to the PrimeFaces Showcase here:  https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/switch.xhtml

Open up a JavaScript console in your browser and type:

```
PF('widget_j_idt638').stopSlideshow();
```

Notice the "Zoom" slideshow has stopped?  So 'widget_j_idt638' is a poorly named widgetvar you called yours widgetVar="images" so you could then do...

```
PF('images').stopSlideshow();
```

Now from reading the documentation for the [Jquery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html) that ImageSwitch uses there is an autostop method.

> autostop:      0,     // true to end slideshow after X transitions
>   (where X == slide count)

So to enable this on your page simply add this inline script to run after the page loads...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   PF('images').jq.cycle({autostop:1});
});
```

That will do the trick. I just tested it in the PrimeFaces showcase.

Comment: @c0nf1ck: What Melloware did here is to start finding out (by looking at the source) what javascript library the component is based on. That can help tremendously.